# Can you add a preprocessor directive for a C# version?

Tags: c#, version, preprocessor-directive

Is there a way to add a preprocessor directive that compares the C# version used by the compiler?

For example :

```
public T MyMethod<T>()
{
#if CS_7
    return default; // Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use 7.1 or greater.
#else
    return null; // Ignore the fact that this won't work, it isn't the point of the question
#endif
}
```

Would the .NET version be the way to go here? Wouldn't there be situations where the compiler used is different for the same project? (i.e. if different employess use different versions of Visual Studio)

Comment: Once it's compiled, the C# version won't matter. Do you intend to deliver this in source form?

Comment: The project is used as a submodule (git) across multiple other projects, so I guess the answer is yes?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have this compiled into each project instead of referenced in a separate assembly? It's very easy to set up a private NuGet server (on-premise or hosted) and publish packages to it.

Comment: I can mention the idea to my superiors, but I don't get to make that decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't, but the C# version used depends on the framework version ([list of version per framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)) used in the project, which provides a default C# version, unless configured otherwise manually through something like the  property (see linked documentation).

Thus, most situations where you would want a C# version preprocessor directive can either be resolved by adding a [framework preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) or forcing a specific C# version in the project itself using the  property in the project file.

Comment: The second link also contains a table of all framework preprocessor symbols